# Bad return type in method reference: Cannot convert Employee to Optional<U>

Tags: java, lambda, option-type, flatmap

I am trying to write a lambda function that gets employee location preference and have the code sample below.

But for my lambda function I get a compilation error at `flatMap(this::buildEmployeeGeolocation)`
saying `Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert com.abc.EmployeeGeolocation to java.util.Optional<U>`.

What am I missing here?

```
public Optional<EmployeeGeolocation> getEmployee(final SessionId sessionId) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(employeePreferencesStore.getEmployeeAccountPreferences(sessionId))
            .map(preferences -> preferences.getPreference(PreferenceKey.Location))
            .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
            .map(this::readEmployeelocation)
            .flatMap(this::buildEmployeeGeolocation);
}

private Optional<EncryptedGeolocation> readEmployeeLocation(@NonNull final String encryptedGeolocation) {
    try {
        return Optional.ofNullable(objectMapper.readValue(encryptedGeolocation, EmployeeGeolocation.class));
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        log.error("Error while reading the encrypted geolocation");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private EmployeeGeolocation buildEmployeeGeolocation(@NonNull final EncryptedGeolocation unditheredEncryptedGeolocation) {
    return EmployeeGeolocation.builder()
            .latitude(10.0)
            .longitude(10.0)
            .accuracy(1.0)
            .locationType(ADDRESS)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you really need to do is swap the `map` and `flatMap`. Change the code

```
.map(this::readEmployeeLocation) 
.flatMap(this::buildEmployeeGeolocation);
```

to

```
.flatMap(this::readEmployeeLocation) // since you already have an Optional<String>
.map(this::buildEmployeeGeolocation); // above results in Optional<EncryptedGeolocation>
```

***Important***: Inferred from the code `Optional.ofNullable(...).map(...).filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)`, that it would result in an `Optional<String>` until this operation.